# How to set camera permission for qrcode scanner with html5

Tags: html, angular, qr-code

I am using the following code to develop a qrcode scanner(source : https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode)

[image]

i am looking the action when user click the Request Camera Permission Button. I want to implement this kind behavior for my code in angular. so i need that action.

i would like to have this behavior

[image]

Can anyone help me for this case? thanks

Comment: Are you just looking for access to the camera from the browser? If so, then [MediaDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) is what you are looking for.

Comment: i want to have some kind permission question if user want to start qr code scanner camera. i edited in my question to make it more clear

Comment: The device itself takes care of that as soon as you start the use of the camera.

Comment: Hmm i think its not like that @Grumpy. You need some code to asking the permission

Comment: More info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia